# bash - copy existing file to existing directory : no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am busy with a server backup script, but the copying is giving some problems.

**file to copy i.e. src**

```
$ ls -la /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 739 Nov  2 14:19 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**destination directory i.e. backupdir**

```
$ ls -la /home/user/backup
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 Feb  1 21:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 48 user user 4096 Feb  1 21:17 ..
```

**code**

```
p="-r"
verbose=true

if $verbose; then
    echo -e "cp $p ${src} ${backupdir}"
    $("cp $p ${src} ${backupdir}")
else
    echo -e "cp $p ${src} ${backupdir}"
    $("cp $p ${src} ${backupdir}") > /dev/null
fi
```

the output of this:

```
cp  -r /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/user/backup/
./backup: line 65: cp -r /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/user/backup/: No such file or directory
```

The output of the command is correct, the execution of the command is correct, the running of the command is problematic, as specified, all source and destination parameters exists, all copy parameters exist.

My conclusion is that `cp` is problematic with bash / bash-scripts

(p.s. running with sudo didn't change anything)

Comment: well, technically you're doing this wrong. `-r` is for recursive directory copies. your source is just a file, not a directory.

Comment: Run it under `strace -f ...` and see what system call is returning `ENOENT`.

Comment: true, but it doesn't make a difference, I copied over the command and ran it by itself in the terminal just as a paranoia soother and it works, with the -r, it still copies the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes and the command substitution are both horribly wrong. The quotes mean you want the shell to find an executable with an absurdly long name with whitespace in it, and the command substitution `$(...)` says to take the output of this (nonexistent) command and run *that* as a command.

You want simply

```
if $verbose; then
    echo -e "cp $p ${src} ${backupdir}"
fi
cp $p "${src}" "${backupdir}"
```

The `echo` command is kind of useless as well; use `set -x` if you want to see exactly what the shell is doing.  (I'm guessing you want to skip the `echo` if `$verbose` is false, and not have two identical clauses inside the `if`...?)  The `if` could be simplified to just `$verbose && echo ...`

Comment: And indeed, the shell reports exactly that very long name as the the one of the file that cannot be found.

Comment: @JohnBollinger how did you "test" for that?

Comment: @tripleee for some reason I used many other functions that worked, but I had to $() the cp, stupid mistake!

Comment: John is reading the output you included, and explains what it means. `backup: line 65: cp -r /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/user/backup/: No such file or directory`